# Getting False value for a key in self.data even when it is not present in the request

Tags: django, angularjs, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 radio buttons in the UI, one for setting a variable (ng-model) say `selected` as `true` (ng-value=true) and other one for setting it as `false` (ng-value=false). Now, when none of them is selected it results in the variable `selected` being absent from the outgoing request (as expected).

However, when that is dealt with Django Forms, `the self.data` dictionary in the `clean()` method gives `False` on accessing `self.data.get('selected')` / `self.data['selected']` why is that so? Shouldn't it be `None` or at least give a `key-error` when it was not even present in the actual request?

Note that the variable 'selected' is actually a field in a Django Model with `default=False`, is that thing responsible for this behaviour? How can I circumvent this situation considering that altering the Django Model field isn't an option?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your form and model code?

Comment: @Rubico I can't share the code but the relevant parts are all normal like Form having having a Meta class for choosing the model and selecting its fields in a tuple etc. Model field  `selected` is also a simple boolean field with default=False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I dealt with it the other day by checking for the `selected` key in the raw `request.body`. Now, since its a string, I had to parse it to a dict and then access the mentioned key using :

```
json.loads(request.body).get('selected')
```

In this way, if `selected` is not present at all when none of the radio buttons are selected, I get `None`. Similarly, if the radio button for `ng-value=true` is selected then I get `True` and vice-versa.